# Gulp + BrowserSync spins up localhost:3000 but never fully loads/connects

Tags: wordpress, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-browser-sync

Whenever I run the Gulp command to spin up the local server to localhost3000, it appears to run in the terminal but it never fully connects in the browser. The loading wheel just keeps spinning endlessly. Below is the Gulp command that is supposed to spin up the server.

```
// ### Watch
// `gulp watch` - Use BrowserSync to proxy your dev server and synchronize code
// changes across devices. Specify the hostname of your dev server at
// `manifest.config.devUrl`. When a modification is made to an asset, run the
// build step for that asset and inject the changes into the page.
// See: http://www.browsersync.io

gulp.task("watch", function () {
  browserSync.init({
    files: ["{lib,templates}/**/*.php", "*.php"],
    proxy: config.devUrl,
    snippetOptions: {
      whitelist: ["/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"],
      blacklist: ["/wp-admin/**"],
    },
  });
  gulp.watch([path.source + "styles/**/*"], ["styles"]);
  gulp.watch([path.source + "scripts/**/*"], ["jshint", "scripts"]);
  gulp.watch([path.source + "fonts/**/*"], ["fonts"]);
  gulp.watch([path.source + "images/**/*"], ["images"]);
  gulp.watch(["bower.json", "assets/manifest.json"], ["build"]);
});
```